# Autosave feature in magento? Is it possible in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to implement the Autosave feature in Magento .

To be more specific: Autosave the values in the text area and save it to backend

Any suggestion or ideas on how it can be done?

ie) While the user is adding any content or editing any post, and when there is an inactivity from him for a long time or closes by mistake, his post should be autosaved. (something like a "save as draft" feature).

Can this be done in magento?

I hear this can be achieved in wordpress, is it possible in magento too?

Answer (score 1):

**No,** In defauld magento this feature is not there. Have to write `custom code`.

Using `keyup` function you have to save into the database.

Something like this you have to use:

```
jQuery('#textarea').keyup(function() {
var content = jQuery(this).val();
/***********Ajax scrip to save into database START******************/
            jQuery.ajax( {
                url : url,
                type : 'post',
                data : data,
                success : function(data) {
                    jQuery('#draftsaved').show();
                }
            });
/***********Ajax scrip to save into database END******************/

});
```

Along with this on load that page need to take those content from database for current customer etc.